# How to format date in a templatefield of a detailsview according to culture

Tags: date-format, detailsview, templatefield

I've been searching a lot on how to this
There is a lot of posts here and there on how to do it
However I cannot find a way to do what I want

I have this textbox in a TemplateField: (I cannot use a BoundField)

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("myDate", "{0:d/M/yyyy}") %>'>
```

That works good, but in my website i can change back and forth from english (us) to spanish (mx) so the date format is different and has to change as well.

en-US: M/d/yyyy es-MX: d/M/yyyy

how can i change that format in a postback?

I tried to have the TEXT intruction in a meta:ResourceKey but it displays '<%# Bind("myDate", "{0:d/M/yyyy}") %>' instead of  the date

I also tried changing it from codebehind using: Text='<%# GetDate(Container.DataItem) %>'

```
    public string GetDate(object dataItem)
    {
        DateTime dt;
        DataRowView _row = (DataRowView)dataItem;
        string fecha = _row["myDate"].ToString();
        if (culture == "es-MX")
            dt = DateTime.ParseExact(fecha, @"d/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        else if(culture == "en-US")
            dt = DateTime.ParseExact(fecha, @"M/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        return dt.ToShortDateString();
    }
```

It does the trick but when I try to update or insert I get a null value error :/
Im using visual studio 2012 .net 4.5 and c#

Thanks for your help

rubenc

Answer (score 0):

Well it turned out that this is a way of doing it

The null error was from another value :)

Thanks anyway